# Access array element by a[0] Or 0[a], what is the practical usage?

Tags: c

**What I know?**

There is an array, `int a[10]`, and to access first element of it, I can either use `a[0]` or `0[a]`; 
which leads to

```
*(a+0) and *(0+a) -> Both results in accessing first element of the array.
```

**What I want to know?**

I want to know whether are any cases where it is more practical to use 0[a] instead of a[0]?

Comment: i don't really understand what you want to know, maybe you could be a bit more clear?

Comment: [useful example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784136/) :)

Comment: if you ask where 0[a] is helpful? well it looks strange and surprising to those who doesn't know the rule so i'd say don't use because it is less readable

Comment: Do we have any usage by any means if we use the syntax 0[a] rather a[0] ?

Comment: Code should be as readable as possible. `0[a]` not only isn't easily readable, it actually causes a wtf. So don't use it.

Comment: @Fred wrong language :P

Comment: Short answer to your question: No

Comment: Longer answer, hell no!

Comment: Here is one case where `0[a]` might be preferable: http://www.ioccc.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's the other way around. `a + b` and `b + a` mean the same thing when one is a pointer and the other is an integer. That leads to `*(a + b)` and `*(b + a)` meaning the same thing, and *that* leads to `a[b]` and `b[a]` meaning the same thing.

There are some cases that are made more readable by adding a pointer to an integer (`i + p`). There are no cases that are more readable by indexing an integer (`i[p]`). Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `int a[10]` no, it is never more practical to write `0[a]`.

FredOverflow links to an example, but it's a bit of a struggle to extract the reason from the comments. So I'll add it as an answer.

`a[0]` and `0[a]` are not *necessarily* equivalent if `a` can be any expression (or for example a macro argument) rather than a simple name.

Suppose `a` expands to `b + 1`. Then `b + 1[0]` is not at all the same thing as `0[b + 1]`.

To cover this awkward case, you could ask whether it's more practical to use `0[a]` instead of `(a)[0]`. To which the answers is still no. Unless maybe you favour brevity over familiarity.

A macro can expand to contain un-matched brackets, like `#define a x]+0[x` or something, so the two still aren't strictly equivalent in all cases. But if `a` is an expression then `0[a]` and `(a)[0]` are equivalent.

Answer (score -5):

**(0+a)** This mean the at a time value increment and **(a+0)** this means after again come then the value is increase

Comment: Yoda? Is that you?