# what is the difference between return 1 and return(1)?

Tags: c, function, return

Is there any difference between the two? this take the program into two different point or what ,please provide all the detail of it. return is a statement, so why even used `return(1)`(looking like a function call), please give the detail of 'how it actually works'?.

Comment: Although the parentheses are redundant in `return`, some argue that they make a difference in other places, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557710/do-parentheses-make-a-difference-when-determining-the-size-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no functional or performance difference at all at run time, since you're either returning the expression `1` or the expression `(1)`, which is the same thing.

It's no different to the following situation, where the statements should have identical run time cost:

```
int a = 42;
int b = (42);
```

There's probably the *smallest* difference at compile time since the compiler has to evaluate more characters in the translation unit but I'd be *very* surprised if it was noticeable.

Comment: so i would assume () is only preferrable when this is some computation take place ahead of return  for more readable of the code .

Comment: @Lea-rner, yes, but you'll *never* need it outside the *entire* expression. In other words, while `return 3 * (7 + 12)` may be necessary for an expression where you want to override the order of evaluation, `return (3 * (7 + 12))` will never be.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference: parentheses in this context do not mean a function call, they are regular parentheses for enforcing a particular evaluation order (which is completely unnecessary here).

C allows programmers to place parentheses around any expressions, for whatever reason they wish, so compiler interprets both versions of the `return` in the same way, as long as parentheses are in balance:

```
return (((((1)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. It's similar to:

```
1 + 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(1) + (2)
```

The latter is legal, but the parenthesis is useless.